# События получения письма/email

Tags: c#, email, pop3

Задача, создать робота, обрабатывающего письмо от определенного отправителя и сохранения вложений в нужную папку. Нашел библиотеку `using OpenPop.Pop3;` использую её. Вопрос, как мне понять, что на сервер пришло новое письмо, идея с таймером мне не нравится, неужели нет способа, по которому почтовый сервер может оповестить о новых письмах? Подписка на какое то события. Перерыл документацию по это библиотеке, ничего не нашел что бы мониторило или получало уведомление от сервера. Подскажите пожалуйста способ или возможно другую библиотеку.

Comment: `идея с таймером мне не нравится` почему?

Comment: @tym32167 раз в минуту дергать сервер, это продуктивно? Я просто хз(

Comment: [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7359345/312041) из забугорья

Comment: раз в минуту - вполне да, имхо

Comment: у меня есть одна_замечательна_платформа, которая "ходит" на pop3 сервер раз в секунду - и с сервером ничего страшного не происходит. `способ, по которому почтовый сервер может оповестить о новых письмах` - это не про pop3 протокол.

Comment: POP3 - старый протокол, который не умеет оповещать об изменениях на почте. Таким умеет заниматься IMAP.